# How to place a div below another div and fill the size?

Tags: html, css

I am converting my desktop project into web, and I have this layout so far. My concern is how can I place my `div` next below another `div` and take/fill the parent width. **My aim is to show (depending on the selected view: list view, kanban view, and form view) lt-list, lt-kanban, and lt-form just below the buttons**. This is what I've done so far:

```
.lt-content { grid-area: content; height: 85vh;}

#lt-button {
    vertical-align:top;
    display: inline-block;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
    float : left;
}

#lt-view {
    vertical-align:top;
    display: inline-block;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
    float : right;
}

#lt-list {
    display: inline-block;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
    float : left;
    background: #9ec4ff;
    width: inherit;
}

#lt-kanban {
    vertical-align:top;
    display: inline-block;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
    float : left;
    background: #a3ffa3;
}

#lt-form {
    vertical-align:top;
    display: inline-block;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
    float : left;
    background: #fff5b7;
}
```

and here is my html:

```
<div class="lt-content">
    <div id="lt-button" style="position: relative">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group" style="background: " aria-label="Basic example">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="border-radius: 0;">CREATE</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="border-radius: 0;">EDIT</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="border-radius: 0;">DELETE</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="border-radius: 0;">SAVE</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="border-radius: 0;">CANCEL</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lt-view">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-floating cyan btn-sm" style="border-radius: 0;"><i class="fas fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-floating cyan btn-sm" style="border-radius: 0;"><i class="fas fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-floating cyan btn-sm" style="border-radius: 0;"><i class="fab fa-wpforms"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lt-list">
        This is a list view....
        <br>
        This is a list view....
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="lt-kanban" style="position: relative">
        This is a Kanban view....
        <br>
        This is a Kanban view....
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="lt-form" style="position: relative">
        This is a Form view....
        <br>
        This is a Form view....
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the image of my layout:

[image]

Comment: Instead of display inline-block you can use flex property to achieve desire logic

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you use the `float: right/left` property afterwards, the `display: inline-block` gets overridden.

You can get the desired results in a number of ways, grid layout, flex, etc. Using floats and the such to make it work won't be the best. Here's an example using flex. I got rid of all the `float`s, `vertical-align` and `inline-blocks`, and wrapped your buttons in a div and added a class.

[Here you go](https://codepen.io/captaindroid/pen/ProQXN)

Answer (score 0):

Change the css for `#lt-button` to be the following:

```
#lt-button {
    display: block;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
}
```

This will get the *list view*, *kanban view*, and *form view* under your buttons. After that you can use js/jQuery (or other scripting language) to show and hide divs based off clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Add two divs, one that wraps `lt-button` and `lt-view`, and another (with id `board`) that wraps the `lt-list`, `lt-kanban` and `lt-form`

Then add this css:

```
.lt-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}
#board {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
}
```

That is, if your objective was to make three columns with those colors, but it will give an idea.